# How to get coordinates of pixel after shape was rectified in emgu 3.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have been trying to get coordinates as described in:
[How to get coordinates of pixel after shape was rectified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589713/how-to-get-coordinates-of-pixel-after-shape-was-rectified)
In Emgu CV 3.0.0.
I am able to warp the image with the following code (stolen from the above link)

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> theWarpedImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\myImage.jpg");
        PointF[] srcs = new PointF[4];
        srcs[0] = new PointF(1533, 2393);
        srcs[1] = new PointF(4169, 1817);
        srcs[2] = new PointF(1765, 1177);
        srcs[3] = new PointF(3717, 621);

        PointF[] dsts = new PointF[4];
        dsts[0] = new PointF(0, 0);
        dsts[1] = new PointF(2950, 0);
        dsts[2] = new PointF(0, 2100);
        dsts[3] = new PointF(2950, 2100);

        PointF[] test = new PointF[4];

        Mat mywarpmat = CvInvoke.GetPerspectiveTransform(srcs, dsts);
        Image<Bgr, byte> theWarpedImage2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\myImage.jpg");
        CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(theWarpedImage, theWarpedImage2, mywarpmat, theWarpedImage2.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Warp.Default, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(0));
```

But I can not get the solution given by Luca Del Tongo to work in version 3.0.0.0

Do you have any suggestions?

And Thanks to MIKI:

```
 var test2=CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(srcs, mywarpmat);
```

Works.

Comment: I think you should call the equivalent of `cv::perspectiveTransform` using the `mywarpmat` on your points coordinates.

Comment: Miki can you add you comment as a answer?

Comment: I can't post C# code.. post your solution and accept it. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miki got the solution. I used:

```
var test2=CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(srcs, mywarpmat);
```

And this worked. Thanks Miki